# WP7 phone not detected by computer

Tags: settings, unlocking

I have an LG E900 WP7 which was locked to orange UK network.

I recently had the phone 'unlocked' to other networks (done by a phone shop) which I believe was done via the MFG app tool so I could go on another network. This was successful but I also wanted to remove all the orange branding so that it was non-specific. I followed some instructions on the xdadeveloper forum however now my phone can't be detected by either Zune or Windows Phone Connector. The phone charges when connected however.

I now have a phone update pending but can't download it. (will this update put it back to 'orange UK' lock?)

I'm afraid to reset back to factory settings as it will remove the unlock and put it back on the orange network.

If anyone can talk me through the steps or post a link so that i can get it to be detected it would be be appreciated.

thanks,
Phil.

Comment: *What* did you try to remove all the branding?

Comment: Can I post links here? I followed the steps on the following site... http://forum.ppcgeeks.com/lg-quantum/142477-hacks-using-mfg-app-debrand-update-unlock-relock.html

Comment: I'm not sure though whether it was the unlocking (network) rather than the messing about in the registry that stopped the phone being detected. If there are any default settings that can undo the steps i have done above and restore the defaults. I don't have the unlock code that the phone shop used though. I should have asked for it!

Comment: I wouldn't expect a hard reset of the phone to reset the carrier lock - you could always try it, and go back to the store saying it isn't working (assuming you have a receipt to prove they unlocked it :)

Comment: Thanks Rowland - i might nip into the store on the way home from work and advise them that i can't get the phone detected by the computer - do a hard reset in front of them and see if the phone still works. I don't have a receipt!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Hard reseting the phone do not lock again.

And I bought My Samsung Focus unlocked with Windows Phone 7 and update with success to Windows Phone 7.5. It made about 4 updates with Zune since I bought.

Comment: Hi Vitor - thanks for the response.Sorry - not very savvy - AFAIK? The unlocking was for network/carrier. This definitely won't lock the carrier back to orange?

Comment: Sorry, AFAIK stands for As Far As I Know. And My Focus was AT&T branded. I bought already carrier unlocked and update it myself. Hope you have the same unlock type.

Answer (score 1):

After much head scratching and help from Vitor and Rowland, I went and did a reset via settings menu. I can confirm the carrier lock does NOT reinstate. I can live with the incorrect branding and all seems to be good again. Will wait and see whether the new network pushes an update again tonight (when I reset I lost it) and we'll see how it goes.